# Fixing few parameters in DEoptim as Integer

Tags: r, optimization, integer, nonlinear-optimization, type-constraints

In DEoptim how to fix parameters as integers in lower and upper bounds
opt <- DEoptim(function,lower = c(0.03,**17**,**5**,0.002), upper = c(0.12,**30**,**15**,-0.5))

In the below example the 2nd, 3rd parameters should be integers but the optimizer takes it as float with upto 6 decimals.

How to fix them as integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we need to create a Mapping function to map  each parameter type. In the above example we have to create the following function,

Mapfun <- function(x){

x[1] <- round(x[1],2) #you can decide to what decimal the optimization to be done by explicit defining the digits here, i need 2 digits

x[2:3] <- round(x[2:3]) #implies that they are integer

x[4] <- round(x[4],3) #here i need 3 digits

}

## Now for using in DeOptim:

opt <- Deoptim(function,lower = c(0.03,17,5,0.002), upper = c(0.12,30,15,-0.5),fnMap = Mapfun)